# How to make single quotation in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have `bridge_id`. How can I concatenate the single quotation in JavaScript?

Javascript code:

```
$('input[type=checkbox][name=print_check]:checked').each(function(i){
  print_ids = print_ids+','+$(this).val();
});
```

Now it's appearing like this:

```
('B51622,D63766,J7473838,K884474,Y838383')
```

But I want it like this:

```
('B51622','D63766','J7473838','K884474','Y838383')
```

How can I generate a single quotation mark in JavaScript?

Comment: Not the best solution, but why not just add the `'`?  `print_ids = print_ids+"','"+$(this).val();` then add a start/closing `'` after the loop:  `print_ids = "'" + print_ids + "'";`

Comment: Hi freedomm-m....it is coming like this not working ('CHCH-03S098XX6868686668'',''CHCH-03S098XX6868686668'','ANAN-01N098ZZ686868657...')

Comment: Here's a working version: https://jsfiddle.net/6rtju8ns/

Comment: They you're putting the wrong `"` or `'` or too many.  Here's ADyson's fiddle with my suggested change (yes, it adds an extra `'',` at the start, but it's only meant as a start / next step from what you had - ie just add the `'` around your values:  https://jsfiddle.net/dLnx4r0e/  Here's a cleaner version using map: https://jsfiddle.net/dLnx4r0e/1/